# How can I display the correct scrollbar when dealing with nested overflows?

Tags: javascript, css, overflow, submenu

When you click the `Services` menu item, everything works properly, but the parent's scrollbar is showing on top of the child's scrollbar. I'm still able to scroll properly inside of the child menu, however that's not emulated with the visible scrollbar.

When I remove `overflow: auto;` from the `.sidebar` container, the child menu scroll works properly, but the parent menu's does not.

How can I make sure the visible scrollbar is for the menu that is active?

```js
( function( $ ) {

 var sidebar = $( '.sidebar' );
  var menu = sidebar.find( '> ul, > div > ul' );

 // submenus
  ( function() {
  
   if ( ! sidebar.length || ! menu.children().length || ! menu.length ) {
     return;
    }
    
    var hasChildren = menu.find( '.has-children > a' );
    var goBack = menu.find( '.go-back' );
    var toggleSub = function( e ) {
     e.preventDefault();
      var _this;
      
      if ( ! $( e.target ).closest( '.go-back' ).length ) {
       _this = $( this );
      } else {
       _this = $( this ).closest( '.sub-menu' ).prev();
      }
      
      _this.find( '~ .sub-menu' ).toggleClass( 'active' );
      _this.closest( 'ul' ).toggleClass( 'slide-out' );
    };
    
    hasChildren.on( 'click', toggleSub );
    goBack.on( 'click', toggleSub );
  
  } ) ();

} ) ( jQuery );
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 280px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fe6570;
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 4px 0px rgba(50,50,50,0.5);
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  line-height: 3.5rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.2);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar ul .has-children > a {
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar ul .has-children > a:after,
.sidebar .go-back > a:before {
  content: '›';
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  right: 1rem;
}

.sidebar .go-back > a:before {
  content: '‹';
  position: relative;
  right: initial;
  left: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.sidebar .sub-menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 280px;
  background: #fe8065;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.sidebar ul {
  overflow-y: auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar .sub-menu.active {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.sidebar .slide-out > li > a {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="has-children">
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="go-back"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Consultations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Design &amp; Planning</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Find a Location</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, change the `.sidebar` element from `overflow: auto;` to `overflow: hidden` when the Services submenu is opened, like this:

```js
( function( $ ) {

 var sidebar = $( '.sidebar' );
  var menu = sidebar.find( '> ul, > div > ul' );

 // submenus
  ( function() {
  
   if ( ! sidebar.length || ! menu.children().length || ! menu.length ) {
     return;
    }
    
    var hasChildren = menu.find( '.has-children > a' );
    var goBack = menu.find( '.go-back' );
    var toggleSub = function( e ) {
     e.preventDefault();
      var _this;
      
      if ( ! $( e.target ).closest( '.go-back' ).length ) {
       _this = $( this );
      } else {
       _this = $( this ).closest( '.sub-menu' ).prev();
      }
      
      _this.find( '~ .sub-menu' ).toggleClass( 'active' );
      _this.closest( '.sidebar' ).toggleClass( 'overflow-off' );
      _this.closest( 'ul' ).toggleClass( 'slide-out' );
    };
    
    hasChildren.on( 'click', toggleSub );
    goBack.on( 'click', toggleSub );
  
  } ) ();

} ) ( jQuery );
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 280px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fe6570;
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 4px 0px rgba(50,50,50,0.5);
  overflow: auto;
}

.overflow-off {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  line-height: 3.5rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.2);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar ul .has-children > a {
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar ul .has-children > a:after,
.sidebar .go-back > a:before {
  content: '›';
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  right: 1rem;
}

.sidebar .go-back > a:before {
  content: '‹';
  position: relative;
  right: initial;
  left: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.sidebar .sub-menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 280px;
  background: #fe8065;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.sidebar ul {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.sidebar .sub-menu.active {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.sidebar .slide-out > li > a {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="has-children">
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="go-back"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Consultations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Design &amp; Planning</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service Item 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Find a Location</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

A few ways to accomplish this, in the example above I've added

```
_this.closest( '.sidebar' ).toggleClass( 'overflow-off' );
```

to the `toggleSub` function, with the `overflow-off` class being:

```
.overflow-off {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, solves a lot of the problems I was facing. What about further nested items though? Like this for example: https://jsfiddle.net/o1sLt5gd/3/ .. by the time I toggle the second level the overflow-off class comes off of the sidebar, and needs to be on all of the previous ul's as well. New question?

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to target the parent `.sidebar`, and any parent `.sub-menu` elements, with something like `_this.closest( '.sidebar, .sub-menu').toggleClass( 'overflow-off' );` Not sure if that will fix everything but should get you close.

Comment: Ah yes, `_this.closest( '.sidebar, .sub-menu' ).toggleClass( 'overflow-off' )` worked!

Comment: Not sure it works entirely, it seems it might cut-off the top of the currently opened sub menu depending on the scroll position when opened. So might need to resolve that.

Comment: Just saw that, I was able to fix it by adding: `_this.closest( '.sub-menu' ).scrollTop( 0 );`